# upload Image in Android through glide or fresco?

Tags: image, android-glide, fresco

Are there some good libraries for upload option for an image form gallery or a new camera capture in android. can we upload image through glide or fresco library or some other library?

Comment: Fresco is for downloading, not uploading. At most you can use it to resize an image before uploading it.

Comment: thanx sir.........:)